# Microservice return response first and then process the request

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, microservices

I am working on a solution for which i am trying to create a microservice which returns response immediately and then processes the request.

I am trying to use Java 8 and Spring for this.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea!

Comment: You could annotate your businesslogic method with an @async so it will be executed asynchronous and the response to the http request can be done immediatly. But if your response depends on the result of this "process" you obviously have to wait until its finished

Comment: I agree with @YannicKlem, the use of '@async' can meet your needs, just be careful with the configuration of thread pool for a good performance. Another option is the ExecutorService, which is easy to use too.

Comment: @YannicKlem  thanks for the suggestion. If possible please share some example. Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: @GiovaniGrifante thanks for the suggestions. If possible please share some example. Thanks again for your responses.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be achieved in several ways.

In order to return a result from the current thread (a controller in this case) while still doing some long-running operation, you will need another thread.

- Use `Executor` directly.

A controller:

```
@Controller
public class AsyncController {

    private AsyncService asyncService;

    @Autowired
    public void setAsyncService(AsyncService asyncService) {
        this.asyncService = asyncService;
    }

    private ResponseEntity asyncMethod(@RequestBody Object request) {
        asyncService.process(new MyLongRunningRunnable());

        // returns immediately
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }
}
```

And a service:

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void create() {
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    public void process(Runnable operation) {
        // no result operation
        executorService.submit(operation);
    }


    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

More details can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

- Another way is to use Spring built-in async capabilities

You can simply annotate a method with `@Async`, having `void` or `Future` return type.

If you still want to supply your own executor, you may implement `AsyncConfigurer` interface in your spring configuration bean.
This approach also requires `@EnableAsync` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

}
```

More on this topic https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example with ExecutorService:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    // Instantiate an executor service
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdonw() {
        // needed to avoid resource leak
        executor.shutdown(); 
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Object gerUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // execute the async action, you can use a Runnable or Callable instances
        executor.submit(() -> doStuff());    
        return "ok";
    }

    private void doStuff(){}
}
```

You can use the Executors factory class to build a ExecutorService. Those methods might help you:

```
java.util.concurrent.Executors
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() // jobs are queued and executed by a single thread
Executors.newCachedThreadPool() // new threads are instantiated as needed and cached
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) // user defined number of threads
```

.

```
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}


import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(1000);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutdownExecutors() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }

}


@Service
public class MyService {

    @Async
    public void doStuff(){
        // Async method
    }

}
```

Both techniques are quite good, but the first one with ExecutorService give you more control.